# What's next step to prove this boolean expression?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to prove that the first member of this equivalence is true:

$$(p\vee q)\wedge (\sim p \wedge (\sim p\wedge q))\equiv \sim p \wedge q$$

I have reached the following point, but I don't know how to continue:

$$(p\vee q)\wedge (\sim p \wedge (\sim p\wedge q))$$
$$=\left \langle Asociativity \ \wedge \right \rangle$$
$$(p\vee q)\wedge (\sim p \wedge \sim p\wedge q)$$
$$=\left \langle Idempotence \ \wedge \right \rangle$$
$$(p\vee q)\wedge (\sim p\wedge q)$$

Some suggestions or tips to continue this proof?

Comment: just note that $q \implies (p \vee q)$

Comment: Hint: $\wedge$ distributes on $\vee$, so the next step is $(p\wedge\sim p\wedge q)\vee (q\wedge \sim p \wedge q)$

Answer (score 1):

You can note that: 
$$p\lor q=(\lnot p\land q)\lor (p\land\lnot q)\lor (p\land q)$$
and:
$$((\lnot p\land q)\lor (p\land\lnot q)\lor (p\land q)) \land (\lnot p\land q)=\lnot p\land q$$.

Answer (score 1):

you can prove that:

(p∨q)∧(∼p∧q) => ∼p∧q < simplification >

∼p∧q => q => p∨q => (p∨q)∧(∼p∧q) < simplification > < addition > < conjunction >

Therfore, (p∨q)∧(∼p∧q) <=> ∼p∧q